# Cannot delete or update a parent row HIBERNATE one to many

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm getting this error when I try to delete a pet. This pet, has visits (child) but I have defined CASCADE.ALL in pet entity. Any idea ?
ERROR:
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`web_customer_tracker`.`visits`, CONSTRAINT `visits_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pet_id`) REFERENCES `pets` (`pet_id`))

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pet_id")
    private int pet_id;

    .....

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "visit_id")
    private Set<Visit> visits;
```

Visit class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "visits")
public class Visit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "visit_id")
    private int visit_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id")
    private Pet pet;

    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using mappedBy in a wrong way
the mappedBy refers to the object name in the opposite side

like this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pet")
private Set<Visit> visits;
```

or if you want to map it by the `JoinColum`  try this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "pet_id")
private Set<Visit> visits;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment, you were right. I changed the annotation, I also changed in others beans that I have with similar annotation and similar structure and now I'm getting an spring compilation error :  "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.luv2code.springdemo.beans.Pet.customer in com.luv2code.springdemo.beans.Customer.pets"

Comment: can you share the full code so i can see what is the problem @AntonioDiaz

Comment: Here you go : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hkFUd01uDqeKIZc69TxWyP-xYUPCPgdW) . Thanks

Comment: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner") in the customer entity

Comment: Hi again, I found the problem I changed the annotation from Customer.pets to  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
Anyway, I'm again in the first error , the one with the foreing key when I try to delete. EDIT : Yup, you are right, but again the first error :(

Comment: as I mention above in the answer the mappedBy should be the variable name in the opposite entity not the class name @AntonioDiaz

Comment: you are right, now it's compiling but not deleting, again same error with the FK

Comment: what are you trying to delete ?

Comment: @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH }) should this to be cascade all i don't see the delete one here maybe it's the problem

Comment: Hi , you are right. Thanks very much man you were so helpful. Just one thing I'm not catching... this is not the other direction ? I mean I coded in that way because I dont want to delete a Pet if I delete a Visit.. surely I'm wrong.. but I'm not understanding :)